# Parallel upload and composition using JAVA libraries of google cloud

Tags: sdk, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client, resumable

I am able to do resumeable upload using the google cloud libraries . But it uploads the chunks in sequential manner .

Is there any way where we can parallelize the upload and then use compose operation as it happens in Gsutil using the client libraries ? .

I read somewhere that google client libraries are not thread safe .

I know there is way of doing the same using the API calls but I don't want to make multiple calls to the same api .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java to perform parallel uploads as you can see in this [Java client library function](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/c3d18ffce9d9895550dd5d2acc1d0ff125305898/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/StorageExample.java#L446). I didn't find a tutorial/working code demonstrating this (not even in the [tutorial using the code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/c3d18ffce9d9895550dd5d2acc1d0ff125305898/google-cloud-examples)).

I didn't have time to create working code but you could give it a try. I already asked to update the tutorial with an example.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! But the library which you referred here does the chunks upload but not in parallel . It uploads the chunks sequentially and then you have to call the compose action .
I want to upload the chunks in parallel way  . I am able to upload a big file in chunks using this library but that is slow as that is sequential upload .

Comment: The client library for Java mentioned above supports a compose operation to compose multiple objects into a single one. The resumable upload is indeed performed sequentially, and in order to support parallel upload of chunks you need to change the architecture of your application so that it support parallel execution of uploads.